# sed search/replace with wildcard

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to do a search/replace in a set of text files. Where the files contain lines like:

```
$table->char('widget_guid', 36)->index('widget_guid');
```

I'm looking to replace the `char` with `guid` and strip out the `, 36`, so the resulting line would look like

```
$table->guid('widget_guid')->index('widget_guid');
```

My effort,

```
sed -i 's/char(\('.*'), 36\)/guid\(\1\)/g' *create*.php
```

but nothing is being replaced

I've tested the expression using regexp101.com and that shows it should picking up the correct blocks, with the correct capture group

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong? And how to achieve what I want?

Comment: suggestion: if you are using online regex helpers, use them only for respective languages... sed has different regex syntax and features than those found in programming languages.. and different sed versions (GNU/osx/etc) themselves have differences.. see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/char(\([^,]*)[^)]*/guid\1/' file

$table->guid('widget_guid')->index('widget_guid');
```

**Explanation:**

- `char`: Match string `char`
- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `\(`: Match literal `(`
  - `[^,]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not comma
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `[^)]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `)`
- `-E` enables extended regex (ERE) instead of basix regex (BRE) in `sed`
- `\1` is back-reference of capture group #1

Answer (score 0):

Following `sed` may help you in same.

```
sed  's/char/guid/;s/, [0-9]*//'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
$table->guid('widget_guid')->index('widget_guid');
```